# detect changes in ember textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I've been developing a new interface where I have a ember textarea:

```
{{textarea value=name cols="80" rows="6"}}
```

But I was wondering how can I detect when the user makes changes (using an action for example) in order to alert him to save or not his work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your specific case:

```
// in your controller

nameObserver: function () {
    var name = this.get('name');
    // maybe compare with old name value
    this.set('isDirty', true); // use this property in your handelbars to show a 'Don't forget to save!' message
}.observes('name')
```

Answer (score 0):

bind to a observed value that is bind to the value of the text area in your controller

for example:

```
txVal: '',
obsTxtVal: function(){
  console.log('Changed', this.get('txVal'));
}.observes('txVal'),
```